# Login is not working correctly on NEXT JS 14.0.1 next-auth 5.0.0.0-beta.4

Tags: next.js, next-auth

My lib:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "14.0.1",
    "bcrypt": "5.1.1",
    "mongoose": "8.0.1",
    "next": "14.0.1",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
    "react": "18",
    "react-dom": "18",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "recharts": "^2.9.0",
    "use-debounce": "^9.0.4"
},
```

The problem is that for some reason the redirection from middleware does not work when logging into the system, while in all other cases it works as it should. When logging out or accessing a page without authorization, the redirection works. But not when logging in.

My middleware

```
//middleware.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "./app/authconfig";

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)'],
}
```

In it I create private roots, and a custom function to define the login export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth; where I pass the config

```
//authConfig.js
export const authConfig = {
    providers: [],
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async authorized({ auth, request }) {
            const isLoggedIn = auth?.user;
            const isOnDashboard = request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
            console.log('auth:', auth, 'isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn, 'isOnDashboard', isOnDashboard)
            if (isOnDashboard) {
                if (isLoggedIn) return true;
                return false;
            } else if (isLoggedIn) {
                return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.nextUrl));
            }
            return true;
        },
    },
};
```

This is a simple function that checks where the user is and whether he is logged in, and redirects him.

```
//auth.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { authConfig } from "./authconfig";
import { connectToDB } from "./lib/utils";
import { User } from "./lib/models";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const login = async (credentials) => {
    try {
        connectToDB();
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: credentials.username });

        if (!user || !user.isAdmin) throw new Error("Wrong credentials!");

        const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
            credentials.password,
            user.password
        );

        if (!isPasswordCorrect) throw new Error("Wrong credentials!");

        console.log('user login', user);
        return user;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to login!");
    }
};

export const {
    handlers: { GET, POST },
    signIn,
    signOut,
    auth
} = NextAuth({
    ...authConfig,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    const user = await login(credentials);
                    console.log('user authorize', user);
                    return user;
                } catch (err) {
                    return null;
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.username = user.username;
                token.img = user.img;
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (token) {
                session.user.username = token.username;
                session.user.img = token.img;
            }
            return session;
        },
    },
});
```

Here I just create {singIn, singOut, auth} according to the new standard next-auth5.beta

In which I export the same config as in middleware and use the Credentials provider where I perform authentication through the login function where I check if the user exists. And I return it.

So, the user can log in peacefully, the system works, but the redirection does not work. Let's start with what works: if the user is logged in and wants to log out, I do...

```
<form action={async () => {
    'use server'
    await signOut()
}}>
    <button className={styles.logout}>
        <MdLogout />
        Logout
    </button>
</form>
```

And the user quietly exits

[signOut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYKnS.png)

On the screenshot, you can see how the middleware works 3 times: the first time it acknowledges that the user is logged in and then logs out. After that, it recognizes that the user has logged out but is still on the dashboard and redirects them to the login page for the third time, showing that they are on the login page and not logged in, which is normal and as it should be. However, when logging in, we see a different picture.

```
//loginForm.jsx
<form action={authenticate} className={styles.form}>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" />
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

```
//authenticate
export const authenticate = async (formData) => {
    const { username, password } = Object.fromEntries(formData);

    try {
        await signIn("credentials", { username, password });
    } catch (err) {
        return "Wrong Credentials!";
    }
};
```

And we get

[signIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUtye.png)

For some reason, I initially receive the processed check from the middleware where there is no authorization, and only then that the user was authorized, but the redirection does not occur. And I can't understand why and how to fix it. I WOULD appreciate your help, because I have been trying to figure it out for 2 days, but to no avail.

I added console.log() to check where the error is, tried removing async, await changing call function to async (e) => {
'use server'
await signOut(e)
}